# How to approximate the caption to the Figure

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm trying to remove all the unecessary space, but I don't know how to proceed here, I already done what is possible to delete all blank space of the graph (the figure starts at the edge of the chart). Does anyone know how to remove or decrease this space?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/pontosdesejados.pdf}\centering
\caption{$r$ fixed points}
\label{desiredpoints}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are countless factors which could be adding that space. Without seeing the code which produces it, it is impossible to answer. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The gap between a figure and its caption is usually defined in the document class, so at least that information is needed.  But there is also a hack:  insert a blank line following the `\includegraphics` line, and on another line, `\vspace{-6pt}` or whatever negative value you find gives the spacing you prefer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton this works very well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With use of the `caption` package you can simply set distance between picture and caption globally:

- without extra distance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0ex]{caption}  % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/pontosdesejados.pdf}\centering
\caption{$r$ fixed points}
\label{desiredpoints}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- with distance of `1ex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figures/pontosdesejados.pdf}\centering
\caption{$r$ fixed points}
\label{desiredpoints}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]